# oracle 12c - does consistent naming of SQL queries help in performance? (eg: query plan reuse)

Tags: oracle, sql-execution-plan

oracle 12c - does consistent naming of SQL queries help in performance? (eg: query plan reuse)

assuming the same query is written in two forms (one in lowercase and the other in uppercase) and gets executed from different parts of an application. Does Oracle consider the queries as same while looking to reuse the query plan?

Answer (score 0):

Q: does consistent [formatting] of SQL queries help in performance?

A: I would say: only in extreme cases.  Execution plans are generated at parse time, so if you have a new query because of different sql text, then you'll have an extra parse/optimize.  At a low scale of differing SQL, no performance impact.  At a high scale of differences (e.g. apps that don't use bind variables AND issue lots of SQL), you put extra pressure on the shared pool and risk having CPU related issues due to resource intensive parse operation.  The individual execution performance of the "different" SQL's will likely be the same as they should get the same execution plan.

Answer (score -1):

By default Oracle identifiers are case insensitive. Uppercase and lowercase query will be seen as one and the same.

Comment: This is true for object names UNLESS they have been created as literals. It is not true for queries.

Comment: Guess I'm used to cursor_sharing=similar.

Comment: Similar is deprecated and will default to force, which converts literal variables to system binds. Has nothing to do with case of queries.

Answer (score -1):

Selecting from V$SQL:

```
select
  SQL_TEXT, SQL_ID, OPEN_VERSIONS, FETCHES, EXECUTIONS, PARSE_CALLS
from
  v$sql;
```

gets different SQL_ID's.

```
SQL_TEXT                         SQL_ID
select * from test where xnum=1  a4hrnbrz05uwy
select * from test where XNUM=1  cgsb5m608anzk
```

Even adding a space into that query will give you a different SQL ID.

I've blogged about it here:

https://timegatetechnologies.wordpress.com/2013/05/30/optimizing-performance-with-cursor-sharing-and-shared-pool-behaviour-in-oracle-11g-r2-11-2-0-3/